# Remove post_content from WooCommerce generated Products post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to remove the first field shown in the image below, but unable to do so. I've successfully managed to remove the "product short description" field, but can't remove the `post_content` field.

**What I've tried:**

```html
add_action('init', 'remove_content');
function remove_content() {
  remove_post_type_support('products', 'editor' );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give this a try:

I think the post type used by woocommerce is `product` and the action you need is `admin_init`

```
add_action('admin_init', 'hide_editor');
        
function hide_editor() {
  remove_post_type_support('product', 'editor');
}
```